# Rerouting URL in PHP to a JS function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I feel like there's an easy answer here but i can't seem to figure it out. Basically there's a URL in our app that's password protected. It reads from a text file in PHP. The $plainTextPasswordPath below is just a variable that gets read from a settings file. Below is the PHP.

```
  <li><a id="help" target="_blank"><?=l(111)?><? echo file_get_contents($plainTextPasswordPath) ?>
```

And here's the JS

```
var domain = /:\/\/([^\/]+)/.exec(window.location.href)[1];
  $(help).attr("href", "https://app-help" + '.' + domain +  "/help")
}
```

Basically what it needs to do is reroute to this where it either authenticates you or loads your password in from your log in.

https://app-help:PASSWORD@SUBDOMAIN.url.com/help

Desired result "Where PASSWORD is the string loaded from the plaintext file and SUBDOMAIN is the current subdomain the user is accessing."

However all I am getting is this https://app-help.local.url.com/help. I am not sure if the @ symbol needs to be in the URL - but I don't think this is allowed?

Thanks

Comment: What's the point of a password if it's visible by everyone?

Comment: The PASSWORD disappears from the URL bar after you're authenticated

Comment: The PASSWORD is still visible in the html source code.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure but this is what is desired - perhaps there's something on the backend they are doing to scramble it.